# Fabric.js - Rotating/change the angle animation with group of shapes every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a group of shapes in fabric.js version 1.6.0-rc.1 and I am trying to animate a rotation for every 2 seconds from the center of the group, I have tried to implement the code from here:

http://fabricjs.com/shadows/

Here is what I came up with:

```
// Group the shapes together.
    patrolGroup = new fabric.Group([circlePatrolPath, patrolManPlusVision], {
      top: 300,
      left: 300,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
    });


patrolGroup.animate({ angle: -360 }, {
      easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutCubic,
      duration: 2000,
      onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      onComplete: function onComplete() {
        console.log(Math.round(patrolManPlusVision.angle)),
        patrolManPlusVision.animate({
          angle: Math.round(patrolManPlusVision.angle) === 360 ? -360 : 360
        }, {
          duration: 2000,
          onComplete: onComplete
        });
      }
    });
```

This only rotates 360 degrees once, I want it to be continuous. I thought the onComplete part would keep it rotating, I can see the angle is changing every two seconds in the console log but this is not being reflected in the animation.

---

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it using javascript interval function:

```
var counter = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
  counter-=5;
  simulatePatrol()

}, 1000);

function simulatePatrol() {
  console.log(counter);
  //patrolGroup.animate({ angle: 60 });
  patrolGroup.animate('angle', counter, {
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
  });
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works. I also found out why the original code was not working. It turns out that I did not bind the events properly. The code now looks like this and is working:

```
var rotationDegrees = -10;
      patrolGroup.animate({ angle: rotationDegrees }, {
        duration: 1000,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        onComplete: function onComplete() {
          //console.log(Math.round(patrolManPlusVision.angle)),
          patrolGroup.animate({
            angle: rotationDegrees-=10
          }, {
            duration: 1000,
            onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
            onComplete: onComplete
          });
        }
      });
```

The `onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),` was needed for each animation.